# getting error while ssh using python

Tags: python, networking, paramiko, cisco

Not able to take ssh of a  device using python getting below error.
Tried reinstalling python paramiko but didnt worked

```
    import paramiko
import sys
import time
paramiko.client.SSHClient()

HOST = "192.168.1.11"
USER = "cisco"
PASS = "cisco"

client1=paramiko.SSHClient()

client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client1.connect(HOST,username=USER,password=PASS)
print "SSH connection to %s established" %HOST
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/testssh.py", line 1, in 
    import paramiko
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko__init__.py", line 31, in 
    from paramiko.client import SSHClient, MissingHostKeyPolicy, AutoAddPolicy, RejectPolicy, WarningPolicy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 24, in 
    import getpass
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop\getpass.py", line 11, in 
    remote_conn_pre=paramiko.SSHClient()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSHClient'

Comment: try `paramiko.client.SSHClient()` instead.

Comment: used this paramiko.client1.SSHClient()  still gives the same error

Comment: not `client1`, `client`

Comment: `import paramiko
import sys
import time
paramiko.client.SSHClient()

HOST = "192.168.1.11"
USER = "cisco"
PASS = "cisco"

client1=paramiko.SSHClient()

client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client1.connect(HOST,username=USER,password=PASS)
print "SSH connection to %s established" %HOST`

Comment: it gives the same error

Comment: can you [edit] your post and show the stacktrace again with the changes?

Comment: i have edited the code still gives the same error

Comment: there's another occurrence of `paramiko.SSHClient()` in your code. read the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
client1=paramiko.SSHClient()
```

to this

```
client1=paramiko.client.SSHClient()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best clue is the last line of the stack trace:

```
line 11, in remote_conn_pre=paramiko.SSHClient()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSHClient'
```

(Added some whitespace for clarity)

Here it is saying that on this line, it can't find the property `SSHClient` in the `paramiko` class.

I would say to check the paramiko documentation, but you can see that you have successfully called this function on line 4:

```
paramiko.client.SSHClient()
```

Which will probably also work on line 11 - as other answers have pointed out, you need to access it through `paramiko.client`, not just `paramiko`. You probably also don't need line 4.